# Bibliography position in PDF output using rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bibtex

I am using RMarkdown to create PDF reports that contain a bibliography. I place this section at the end of the script with `# References` but sometimes, as the document gets more crowded, this section appears randomly placed in the middle of the PDF document.

Is there a way to fix it in the last pages?

My typical YAML header is  :

```
---
title: ""
author: ""
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes  
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  always_allow_html: true
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    df_print: paged
  word_document:
    toc: yes
bibliography: _outliers.bib
link-citations: yes
zotero:
  library: <_outliers>
  scannable-cite: false
  client: <zotero>
  author-in-text: false 
csl: science.csl
```